# Playing with database table using android

Tags: android, sqlite

I curretly making an apps to calculate BMI and at the of the day they can review the progress.So far i manage to create the registration and login page.They only need username and password to register and using the same username and password to lgin.I made one table using sqllite named **user** that store the password and username just nw.once succesful login,user directed to the main page,where they have date and current weight to fill in and click caculate.Here the problem,I dont know how to start after user click calculate.Should I create new table to store the date and weight inserted?but if i do so,how to link the user table with the table that consist the date and weight?or I add another column in user table named date and weight?but i do so,one user can insert data everyday.how to store that?thanks..
Image below the main page for the apps before calculate and put the data in the system.the date inserted is based on the system date.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two tables for that:

Table `user` fields:

1) id 
2) username
3) password

Table `user_logs` fields:

1) id
2) user_id  (this relation to id field in user field)
3) weight
4) height (is we assume height is changing)
5) date

To add record:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("username","my_username");

values.put("password","my_password")

int id= db.insert("user", null, values);
```

Link will help you to understand sqlite with android: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: now i see the flow...so the user_id will act as a foreign key??but how to get the id from user table and put it as foreign key in user logs table??i never saw that kind of code before..

Comment: I am adding solution to answer

Comment: thanks mate...but how it is work??sory..

Comment: Here the link that will help you to use sqlite database with android [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)